# Display Yes/No from bit by default

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a column that is of type 'bit'. I want the column to display either the word yes (1) or (0) if no. Is there somewhere I can set this?

If not is there a replacement for boolean I can use? True/false will do fine as a replacement

I am using SQL Server-management 2008 R2

I'm trying to amend the table.

Comment: Display _where_?  You can convert to a string but then your output will be a string, not a bit.

Comment: Please amend your question to describe what you are attempting to accomplish.  Are you writing a query or editing directly against a table?  If you are writing a query, are you only looking at the results in SSMS or are you using the query in an app?

Comment: @DStanley When a query is executed on the database I'd like it to display yes/no OR true/false but I need to use a bit format if true/false is not used. I originally tried to use a boolean but that doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @JamesCurtis Editing against a table

Comment: its going to have to be on a query by query basis, using the case statement provided by Dmitry below.

Comment: @user3245390 My point is _displaying_ data is the job of the presentation layer.  You _can_ modify your query to return "true" or "false" but then the client is dealing with _strings_, not _bits_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `case`:

```
select case 
         when MyBitField = 1 then
           'yes'
         else
           'no' 
       end
  from MyTable
```

Comment: Be aware that this query changes the _type_ of the data returned.  Clients will no longer be able to use boolean operators on the returned data.